# Neural networks and distributed computing for parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, machine-learning, neural-network

In a neural network are your just really calculating many consecutive sums. However, my reasoning isn't totally clear on the deeper technical issues with existing software packages.

There are many software technologies and each one seems to have a specific parallelization focus. I am trying to pin down what software technology to use.

- openMP - many cores or cpu's on a single machine.
- MPI/MPICH - many machines on a network
- hybrid - openMP for the local machines  wrapped in MPI/MPICH

Comment: With neural networks you likely want to use a GPU.

Comment: yes that is probably true. There are however hardware limitations in this case.